# pgr_alphashape returns a self intersecting polygon

Tags: postgis, sql, pgrouting

After using the function pgr_drivingdistance() I am attempting to make a polygon with pgr_alphashape. Following the example found in the documentation I should do the following: https://docs.pgrouting.org/2.4/en/pgr_alphaShape.html#pgr-alphashape

```
--Create a table with 1 Polygon where the agg_cost is lower then 5
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp.polygon; 
CREATE TABLE schema.polygon as  
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_AddPoint(foo.openline, 
    ST_StartPoint(foo.openline)))
    FROM (
SELECT ST_MakeLine(points ORDER BY id) AS openline
FROM (
    SELECT ST_MakePoint(x, y) AS points, row_number() over() AS id
    FROM pgr_alphaShape('
        SELECT 
            source::integer as id, 
            ST_X(the_geom)::float as x, 
            ST_Y(the_geom)::float as y,
            agg_cost as cost
        from 
            temp.exampleresult as kar
        INNER JOIN schema.table_vertices as vert
        ON kar.source = vert.id
        where agg_cost < 5;')   
    ) AS a
) AS foo;
```

It works and it generates a polygon. However the polygon is self intersecting and has a weird shape. Where should I be looking to debug?

So the goal is to create after a nicely filled network with pgr_drivingdistance() a polygon which is based on the agg_cost.

This is what I am aiming for: https://anitagraser.com/2011/02/12/drive-time-isochrones/

I suppose the sequence of my points is not correct.

Ok so without my join of the agg_cost it works perfectly for all vertices. But with the join it does not:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp.polygon; 
CREATE TABLE schema.polygon as  
SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_AddPoint(foo.openline, 
    ST_StartPoint(foo.openline)))
    FROM (
SELECT ST_MakeLine(points ORDER BY id) AS openline
FROM (
    SELECT ST_MakePoint(x, y) AS points, row_number() over() AS id
    FROM pgr_alphaShape('
        SELECT 
            source::integer as id, 
            ST_X(the_geom)::float as x, 
            ST_Y(the_geom)::float as y,
            agg_cost as cost
        from 
            schema.table_vertices') 
    ) AS a
) AS foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my memory, there is a case which alpha shape result includes multi polygons with separator (coordinate x = null and y = null).

So, could you check the separator or just try to use pgr_pointsAsPolygon function which support such multi polygons case ?

[pgr_pointsAsPolygon — pgRouting Manual (2.4)]
https://docs.pgrouting.org/2.4/en/pgr_pointsAsPolygon.html#pgr-points-as-polygon

You can see pgr_pointsAsPolygon logic at here.
https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/v2.4.2/src/alpha_shape/sql/alpha_shape.sql#L59-L93